Optional Key in Response Object Verification in Karate
Our application uses different response schema for some of the endpoints. (I know, I know).
Example 1
{
    "status": #number,
    "message": "#string",
    "success": "#boolean"
}

Example 2
{
    "status": #number,
    "message": "#string"
}

Does Karate support OR in schema validation? What's the best way to verify the response object?

This is actually quite easy with the optional matcher: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#optional-fields
Try:
{
  "status": #number,
  "message": "#string",
  "success": "##boolean"
}

